# PHP session warning in Windows IIS

Tags: php, session, iis-8

> Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.
>
> session_start(): open(C:\Windows\TEMP\sess_3ls3qdk77m9mhsf5tm1cdhrm05bi5kb1, O_RDWR) failed: Invalid argument (22)

in my php.ini file: `session.save_path = "C:\temp\phpsessions"`
Before it was working fine. So sudden it is showing an error.
anyone can assist with this please.

Comment: Can anyone please help? It will greately appreciated

Comment: I have the same problem and am using SQL Server and my custom site with IIS

Comment: Thank you everyone for all your suggestion. It is working fine now.

Answer (score 8):

As already stated by other, there is a chance that

1. Either the **C:\temp\phpsessions directory doesn't exist**,Or
2. Else IIS_IUSRS Read/Write Permission is missing in **C:\Windows\Temp**

there is no problem with your browser.

Answer (score 3):

**PHP will not create this directory structure automatically**. So make sure this **C:\temp\phpsessions** directory exist. If not, then        you can use the **script** in the ext/session dir for that purpose or create that directory structure **manually**.

**and then**

You can change session save path by writing this line for created directory before session start also note here extra '\' because of escape character.

```
session_save_path("C:\\temp\\phpsessions");
```

Comment: Could you please explain in a bit more detail? I can't find any ext/session directory, and what do you mean by `script`- a .bat file?

Answer (score 3):

Double check the permissions on C:\Windows\Temp\ folder.   I think IIS_IUSRS needs to have write access in order for files to be saved.

Consider moving the session folder out of C:\Windows\

Where ever you put the sessions, iis will need permissions to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it is browser problem. Some mistmatch between browser and session data.

Just in case please do the following:
1. Clear the cache, cookies and temp data of your browser (or use another browser for experimental purposes). 
2. Clear the directory where session files are stored on serverside (in your case it seems it is C:\Windows\TEMP or C:\temp\phpsessions. Better clean both of them).

If it does not work please share your php.ini file.