# opendir on IIS10 and PHP 8

Tags: php, iis, scandir, opendir

I have recently been setting up a corporate server to put my website online.

Previously this website was hosted on my pc using XAMPP with PHP 5; now I have Windows Server 2019 and PHP 8.
Everything works, but something is wrong in **opendir()** and **scandir()**: it says folders are either non-existent or cannot be accessed.

My company has multiple servers and I have to log in via PHP to process other data there, but you can't log in via PHP. With folder browsing on Windows Server everything is accessible and visible, while PHP fails.

Could you help me? I'm really ignorant of the subject...

The very simple code is this:

```
$directory="//artioscad/Artios/Designs/rapporti di lavoro/Done/";
$directory_handle=opendir($directory);
$c=scandir($directory);
```

The error that appears is this:

```
PHP Warning:  opendir(//artioscad/Artios/Designs/rapporti di lavoro/Done/): Access is deni (code: 5) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\amministrazione\rapportini.php on line 59
PHP Warning:  opendir(//artioscad/Artios/Designs/rapporti di lavoro/Done/): Failed to open directory: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\amministrazione\rapportini.php on line 59
PHP Warning:  scandir(//artioscad/Artios/Designs/rapporti di lavoro/Done/): Access is deni (code: 5) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\amministrazione\rapportini.php on line 63
PHP Warning:  scandir(//artioscad/Artios/Designs/rapporti di lavoro/Done/): Failed to open directory: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\amministrazione\rapportini.php on line 63
PHP Warning:  scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\amministrazione\rapportini.php on line 63
```

I have also changed the permissions of the IUSR user, but it still doesn't work...[IUSR permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SDC7.png)

Comment: Seems like you dont have enough permission to access the folder. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57497100/14066311 if it helps

Comment: I have already tried to change the permissions for the IUSR user, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: You can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39141501/php-session-warning-in-windows-iis

Comment: this doesn't work either......

Comment: Whether it is the parameter in the method is incorrect, or the format problem, you can use this reference to troubleshoot: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-opendir-function/